# Validating the TextField when using inline editable

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I'm using material table with inline editing mode, and now I want to all of inline editing fields are required, if the user leaves the input is empty or something like that, material table should display error message and disable the buttons.

At the moment, I have to use the editComponent to override the input. is there anyway to I can do it by material table without overriding?

Comment: No that's not possible and that why the override is there to customize it to your needs.

Comment: Material table will provide something for you soon since it's getting yup validation support soon.

Comment: @Domino987 thank you for your answer, till there we should use customize the component manually I guess

Answer (score 0):

I made it work like this

```
{ 
   field: 'name', 
   title: 'Name', 
   validate: (rowData) => rowData.name=== "" ? {isValid:false, helperText:'Name is required'}:true, 
   editComponent: props => { return <TextField value={props.value} 
                             onChange={(event) => {props.onChange(event.target.value)}} 
                              error={props.error} helperText={props.helperText}/>}
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.